# yii2 + elasticsearch: How to use 'sort' with 'query' in search

Tags: yii2

Info: Using "yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch": "2.1.x-dev"

I would like to do the following using yii2 elastic:
(from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

```
{
    "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "location" : {
                    "lat" : -33.936593,
                    "lon" : 18.4204544
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "km"
          }
      }
  ],
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "3000km",
                    "location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.936593,
                        "lon" : 18.4204544
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the below:

```
$query = [
            'bool' => [
//                    'must' => [
//                        'match_all' => [] // this throws a diff error
//                    ],
                'filter' => [
                    'geo_distance' => [
                        'distance' => $distance . "km",
                        'location' => [
                            'lat' => $lat,
                            'lon' => $lng
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $sort = [
            'geo_distance' => [
                'location' => [
                    'lat' => $lat,
                    'lon' => $lng
                ],
                'order' => 'asc',
                'unit' => 'km'
            ]
        ];

        $models = Model::find()
            ->query($query)
            ->orderBy($sort)
            ->all();
```

I get error:

> Exception 'yii\elasticsearch\Exception' with message 'Elasticsearch
>   request failed with code 400. Response body:
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[field_sort]
>   unknown field [location], parser not
>   found"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[field_sort]
>   unknown field [location], parser not found"},"status":400}'

Maybe I can pass raw json query to yii2 elasticsearch? Not sure the yii2-elasticsearch lib is able to handle a 'location' (geo_distance) field yet ?

Help appreciated,
gvanto

Answer (score -1):

you can use `orderBy` method and write something like this

```
MyModel::find()
  ->query(...)
  ->orderBy([
    'post_date' => SORT_ASC,
    'name' => SORT_DESC
  ])
  ->all()
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir tried this, doesn't work ... I ended up doing this with a pure curl call using guzzle ...